# PHP - combine values from Objectlist with same key

Tags: php, arrays

I have an objectlist:

```
$deliveryOptions = 
 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [item_id] => 55 [value] => delivery-online ) 
        [1] => stdClass Object ( [item_id] => 55 [value] => delivery-campus ) 
        [2] => stdClass Object ( [item_id] => 56 [value] => delivery-campus ) 
        [3] => stdClass Object ( [item_id] => 81 [value] => delivery-blended ) 
       )
```

I need to format it to an array:

```
$combined =
( [item_id] => 55 [course-delivery] => array( "delivery-online","delivery-campus")
( [item_id] => 56 [course-delivery] => delivery-campus )
( [item_id] => 81 [course-delivery] => delivery-blended )
```

My code so far:

```
foreach ($deliveryOptions as $row)
{  
    $temp = array('item_id'=>$row->item_id,                  
                   'course-delivery'=>$row->value
                    );        
    $course[] = $temp;  
}

foreach ($course as $row)
{    
  $match = array_search($row['item_id'], array_column($combined, 'item_id'));
   
  if(is_numeric($match))
  {
     $combined[$match]['course-delivery'][] = $row['course-delivery'];       
  }
  else{
    array_push($combined, [
        'item_id' => $row['item_id'],
        'course-delivery' => array($row['course-delivery'])
    ]);         
  }   
}
```

The format of $combined might seem odd, but I have three different queries creating different object lists that all need to be combined into one JSON array based on 'item_id' as the key.
I have the part where all three get combined working, this new array configuration comes from a checkbox situation, thus the need to combine the different values off the same item_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for another `foreach`, you just create the structure along the way. First, initialize the container for the particular `item_id`.

When an `item_id` hits again and is not an array, just overwrite it, use the first value (string) and turn it to an array and finally push the value.

```
$deliveryOptions = [
    (object) ['item_id' => 55, 'value' => 'delivery-online'],
    (object) ['item_id' => 55, 'value' => 'delivery-campus'],
    (object) ['item_id' => 56, 'value' => 'delivery-campus'],
    (object) ['item_id' => 81, 'value' => 'delivery-blended'],
];

$combined = [];
foreach ($deliveryOptions as $row) {
    if (!isset($combined[$row->item_id])) { // initialize if it doesn't exist
        $combined[$row->item_id] = (array) $row; continue;
    }
    if (!is_array($combined[$row->item_id]['value'])) { // if another occurence
        $temp = $combined[$row->item_id]['value']; // get the string initial value
        $combined[$row->item_id]['value'] = []; // turn it into an array
        $combined[$row->item_id]['value'][] = $temp; // and reassign and push inside the array
    }
    $combined[$row->item_id]['value'][] = $row->value; // push the value in the array
}

// $combined = array_values($combined); // array key reindex if needed
```

[Sample output](https://www.tehplayground.com/7lcOyNQB4TSz2Ayw)

Comment: This works, thanks! I have not tried casting (array) in front of the value before or using continue.

Comment: @hpgodwin yes it's just typecasting on each `$row` since the input you have is an object on your example, glad this helped. the `continue;` just skips the current iteration so that it doesn't execute the rest of the code block.